# capture multiple column names as value in single column pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I just want to capture the subject name (column name) as value in new column where there is some improvements in the students marks after re-evaluation.

I have the dataset before re-evaluation:

| name | class | exam | maths | physics | chemistry | joining date | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Grade - 10 | model 1 | 98 | 78 | 35 | 2000-01-15 | fail |
| Bob | Grade - 06 | mid term | 65 | 52 | 92 | 2001-08-16 | pass |
| Rose | Grade - 06 | model 2 | 91 | 70 | 54 | 2001-09-14 | pass |
| Michael | Grade - 07 | model 1 | 10 | 90 | 45 | 2010-01-10 | fail |

Now I have the dataset after re-evaluation, there are some improvements in some students marks, and there are new data on other students marks who took their exam recently,

| name | class | exam | maths | physics | chemistry | joining date | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Grade - 10 | model 1 | 98 | 78 | **87** | 2000-01-15 | **pass** |
| Bob | Grade - 06 | mid term | 65 | **91** | 92 | 2001-08-16 | pass |
| Rose | Grade - 06 | model 2 | 91 | 70 | 54 | 2001-09-14 | pass |
| Michael | Grade - 07 | model 1 | **100** | 90 | 45 | **2001-01-10** | **pass** |
| Sam | Grade - 08 | mid term | 43 | 62 | 80 | 2000-08-10 | pass |
| James | Grade - 10 | model ` | 76 | 66 | 96 | 2000-09-07 | pass |
| Henry | Grade - 09 | model 1 | 34 | 91 | 70 | 2000-01-04 | fail |

Now, we need to concat these two datasets, and mark which row is updated, and which column got updated, so, the concatenated dataset looks like this,

| name | class | exam | maths | physics | chemistry | joining date | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Grade - 10 | model 1 | 98 | 78 | 35 | 2000-01-15 | fail |
| Bob | Grade - 06 | mid term | 65 | 52 | 92 | 2001-08-16 | pass |
| Rose | Grade - 06 | model 2 | 91 | 70 | 54 | 2001-09-14 | pass |
| Michael | Grade - 07 | model 1 | 10 | 90 | 45 | 2010-01-10 | fail |
| John | Grade - 10 | model 1 | 98 | 78 | **87** | 2000-01-15 | **pass** |
| Bob | Grade - 06 | mid term | 65 | **91** | 92 | 2001-08-16 | pass |
| Rose | Grade - 06 | model 2 | 91 | 70 | 54 | 2001-09-14 | pass |
| Michael | Grade - 07 | model 1 | **100** | 90 | 45 | **2001-01-10** | **pass** |
| Sam | Grade - 08 | mid term | 43 | 62 | 80 | 2000-08-10 | pass |
| James | Grade - 10 | model ` | 76 | 66 | 96 | 2000-09-07 | pass |
| Henry | Grade - 09 | model 1 | 34 | 91 | 70 | 2000-01-04 | fail |

Now, the final output should look like this, with 2 new columns, I was able to eliminate the duplicates and added the new columns **any improvement**, but I got stuck on adding the other new column **improved subject**

**Expected Output:**

| name | class | exam | maths | physics | chemistry | anyimprovement | improvedfield |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Grade-10 | model 1 | 98 | 78 | **87** | Yes | chemistry,result |
| Bob | Grade-06 | mid term | 65 | **91** | 92 | Yes | physics |
| Rose | Grade-06 | model 2 | 91 | 70 | 54 | No | no improvement |
| Michael | Grade-07 | model 1 | **100** | 90 | 45 | Yes | maths,result,joining date |
| Sam | Grade-08 | mid term | 43 | 62 | 80 | New Entry | new entry |
| James | Grade-10 | model ` | 76 | 66 | 96 | New Entry | new entry |
| Henry | Grade-09 | model 1 | 34 | 91 | 70 | New Entry | new entry |

Below is the code, I used for this,

```
added primary key column by concatenating name, class, exam and secondary key column by concatenating maths,physics,chemistry.

dupedf = concatdf.loc[concatdf.duplicated(subset=['PrimaryKey', 'SecondaryKey'],keep=False)]

dupedf1 = concatdf.loc[concatdf.duplicated(subset=['PrimaryKey'],keep=False)]

for i,j in dupedf.iterrows():
    for k,l in dupedf1.iterrows():
        if l['PrimaryKey'] == j['PrimaryKey']:
            
            dupedf = dupedf.drop_duplicates(subset=['PrimaryKey','SecondaryKey'],keep='last')
            dupedf['any improvement'] = 'No'
            # dupedf['improved subject'] = ' '

        else:
            dupedf1 = dupedf1.drop_duplicates(subset=['SecondaryKey'],keep=False)
            
            dupedf1 = dupedf1.drop_duplicates(subset=['PrimaryKey'],keep='last')
            dupedf1['any improvement'] = 'Yes'
           # dupedf1['improved subject'] = 'column name'
```

in the above code, I am iterating only the rows which exists in both before & after re-evaluation datasets. iterating row by row to have fill the 2 new columns **anyimprovement & improvedfield.** **I was able to achieve for anyimprovement column, but I need help with improvedfield column.**

Comment: Kindly add the expected final output dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use a loop with `iterrows`, try vectorial code instead.

Assuming `df1` and `df2` the two inputs:

```
# define ID columns
cols = ['name', 'class', 'exam']

# ensure having dates (optional)
df1['joining date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['joining date'])
df2['joining date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['joining date'])

# comparing the values
tmp = (df1.assign(**{'new entry': False}).set_index(cols)
          .lt(df2.set_index(cols).assign(**{'new entry': True}))
          .eval('`new entry` = ~`new entry`') # reverse flag
      )

# producing output
out = (df2.merge(tmp.mul(tmp.columns).where(tmp).stack()  # identifying columns that changed
                    .groupby(level=cols).agg(','.join)
                    .rename('improvedfield'),
                 left_on=cols, right_index=True, how='left')
          # adding anyimprovement column from the NA or new entry status of improvedfield
          .assign(anyimprovement=lambda d: np.select([d['improvedfield'].eq('new entry'),
                                                      d['improvedfield'].notna()],
                                                     ['new entry', 'yes'], 'no'
                                                    ))
          .fillna({'improvedfield': 'no improvement'})
      )
```

Output:

```
      name       class      exam  maths  physics  chemistry joining date result     improvedfield anyimprovement
0     John  Grade - 10   model 1     98       78         87   2000-01-15   pass  chemistry,result            yes
1      Bob  Grade - 06  mid term     65       91         92   2001-08-16   pass           physics            yes
2     Rose  Grade - 06   model 2     91       70         54   2001-09-14   pass    no improvement             no
3  Michael  Grade - 07   model 1    100       90         45   2001-01-10   pass      maths,result            yes
4      Sam  Grade - 08  mid term     43       62         80   2000-08-10   pass         new entry      new entry
5    James  Grade - 10   model `     76       66         96   2000-09-07   pass         new entry      new entry
6    Henry  Grade - 09   model 1     34       91         70   2000-01-04   fail         new entry      new entry
```